# Найти все слова в которых не встречается кавычка

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, которое в предложении:

> Well, maybe I shouldn't be dating such an old man.

Находило бы все слова, но только те, в которых нет **'**

Пробовал:

`[a-zA-Z]+[^']` но находит **shouldn**'t

`[a-zA-Z]+(?!')` но находит также **should**n't и так же shouldn'**t**

Comment: PHP? Java? .NET?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(?<![a-z]')\b[a-z]+\b(?!'[a-z])/i
```

`\b[a-z]+\b` - ищет слово состоящее из букв a-z и A-Z;
`(?<![a-z]')` - проверяет чтобы перед найденным словом не было одинарной кавычки, а перед ней a-z или A-Z;
`(?!'[a-z])` - проверяет чтобы за найденным словом не следовала одинарная кавычка, а затем a-z или A-Z.

P.S. Решение для php.
P.P.S. Тест https://regex101.com/r/lb4Cle/1

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно сделать такое выражение

```
/[a-zA-Z]+'[a-zA-Z]+/
```

Если, по-умолчанию, поиск жадный

Тест: https://regex101.com/r/lb4Cle/2